I can't execute Python code on the terminal after writing a code in VS Code
I have installed Python correctly with path selection. However, I can't execute the code on the terminal after writing a code in VS Code. It does not give me any error messages when I type python filename.py. It just stays empty. I can't find the cause of it and getting frustrated to fix it. Please help.
Re-installed Python, added extension code runner on vs code and also added the other python extension.

You should add some code and a minimal reproducible example, because as it is it's quite impossible for us to understand what's going on

it sounds like your python code is simply not running anything. Do you maybe only have defined some functions but are not executing any of them? Or does your code perhaps work but not print anything?

I very much agree with Federicofkt here, without more details it's hard to know what the exact issue is, but I'll try my best to answer.
Try running python -v or python3 -v on powershell (assuming your OS is Windows), if you got an error it would most likely mean you did not install or configure python correctly. In that case, you can follow https://realpython.com/add-python-to-path/ to add Python to path.
In the event that there's no error, cd to your directory and try python xxx.py or python3 xxx.py directly on your powershell command line and it will compile.
If your terminal returns empty with no errors then that most likely means your code successfully compiled and nothing is returned since it's how your code is configured.
